# How to change the VisualStudio compiler version?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I have a small project that I try to build on different platforms. It went smooth on Linux, but on Windows, I keep struggling.

It seems the library I use `SFML` require a specific version of the Visual C++ compiler. I've downloaded the *Visual C++ 15 (2017) - 64-bit* version of the library, but I have installed Microsoft Visual Studio 2022 (I don't know which version I have though).

How can I configure my project to use the VC2015 compiler?

Perhaps my issue is somewhere else because I get unresolved references:

```
1>CMakeCCompilerId.obj : error LNK2005: main already defined in CMakeCXXCompilerId.obj
1>main.obj : error LNK2005: main already defined in CMakeCXXCompilerId.obj
1>sfml-graphics-s-d.lib(Texture.cpp.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol glFlush referenced in function "public: __cdecl sf::Texture::Texture(class sf::Texture const &)" (??0Texture@sf@@QEAA@AEBV01@@Z)
1>sfml-graphics-s-d.lib(Shader.cpp.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol glFlush
1>sfml-graphics-s-d.lib(RenderTextureImplFBO.cpp.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol glGetIntegerv
1>sfml-graphics-s-d.lib(Texture.cpp.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol glGetIntegerv
1>sfml-graphics-s-d.lib(GLExtensions.cpp.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol glGetIntegerv
1>sfml-graphics-s-d.lib(TextureSaver.cpp.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol glGetIntegerv
```

Comment: But SFML projects can be compiled in VS2022 using `/std:c++20`. At least in my case. Maybe my SFML version is more recent. I'm not sure though.

Comment: I don't understand why the project fail to link. I've tried with the release and the version I just built: I hate Visual Studio, I always spend hours configuring a project while it takes me only a fraction of time on Linux :(

Comment: Another factor is which Windows SDK version are you compiling against.

Comment: Project (not Solution) Properties > Configuration Properties > General > Platform Toolset

Comment: So the linker is finding the sfml-graphics-s-d.lib but that library relies on OpenGL and the linker can't find those functions.  The tutorial page says You will then need to link your program to the OpenGL library. Unlike what it does with the headers, SFML can't provide a unified way of linking OpenGL. Therefore, you need to know which library to link to according to what operating system you're using ("opengl32" on Windows, "GL" on Linux, etc.).

OpenGL functions start with the "gl" prefix. Remember this when you get linker errors, it will help you find which library you forgot to link.

Comment: I find the easiest way to manage external libraries in VS is using `vcpkg`.  Installing SFML should then be a single command which will automatically bring in any needed dependencies too.

Comment: VS 2015 Update 3, VS 2017, VS 2019, and VS 2022 are 'binary compatible' for static libraries, so that's not the problem. The symbols you are missing are not in the Visual C/C++ Runtime. See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/binary-compat-2015-2017?view=msvc-170)